# Slow queries with MySQL large database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `ipaddresses` that contains IP ranges. Columns are: ipStart, ipEnd

Example of

```
ipStart: 3579374832
ipEnd: 3579374839
```

Now I want to select 300ish IP addresses from another table: `visit_count`. And based on those 300 addresses I want to check if the ip address is in the range of any of IPs in the table `ipaddresses`

My current code:

```
$results = $database->query("SELECT user_id, 
                            DATE_FORMAT(last_visit, '%Y-%m-%d') as datumet, 
                            cookieId, ipaddress 
                          FROM `visit_count` 
                          WHERE last_visit BETWEEN 
                                      '$firstDayOfMonth' AND '$lastDayOfMonth' 
                          AND user_id = '$userId' 
                          GROUP BY cookieId 
                          ORDER BY last_visit ASC");        

$rows = $database->loadObjectList($results);    


foreach ( $rows as $row ) {

    $ipaddressLong = ip2long($row->ipaddress);

    // This is where its very very slow
    $selO = $database->query("SELECT ipStart, ipEnd FROM `ipaddresses` 
                        WHERE '$ipaddressLong' BETWEEN `ipStart` AND `ipEnd`");
    $rowO = $database->getrow($selO);

}
```

The result is a really slow query that consumes a lot of cpu.

`ipaddresses` has indexes for both `ipStart` and `ipEnd` and contains around 50k rows.

How can I make this go faster?

Comment: Any reason you can't do a join? Does the ipaddress table have a covering index on both ipStart and ipEnd (MySQL generally only ever uses one index on one table, hence if 2 columns would help a query then the index should cover both of them)

Comment: Not to familiar with joins, no idea how to implement that

Comment: Can you create an index on both `ipStart` and `ipEnd`?

Comment: @web-nomad yepp I just did it now

Comment: Please post the result of: EXPLAIN SELECT ipStart, ipEnd FROM `ipaddresses` WHERE '$ipaddressLong' BETWEEN `ipStart` AND `ipEnd`"

Comment: select_type: Simple, Extra: using where; Using index

Comment: Reason to use a join is that it would mean you would be doing 1 query rather than 300 queries. The main oddity about this is that you store the ip address in 2 different formats on the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty change to a single query using a JOIN:-

```
SELECT a.ipStart, a.ipEnd 
FROM `ipaddresses` a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, DATE_FORMAT(last_visit, '%Y-%m-%d') as datumet, cookieId, inet_aton(ipaddress ) AS ipaddressLong
    FROM `visit_count` 
    WHERE last_visit BETWEEN '$firstDayOfMonth' AND '$lastDayOfMonth' 
    AND user_id = '$userId' 
    GROUP BY cookieId 
) b 
ON b.ipaddressLong BETWEEN a.ipStart AND a.ipEnd
```

Note that this could probably be simplified. However it depends on your use of *GROUP BY cookieId* . At the moment this is going to get one row per cookie id, but which row is undefined (ie, could be any user_id, ip address and last visit date that goes with that cookie id).

Comment: When running EXPLAIN i get user_id using filesort. Query takes 11sec

Comment: Can you post you table declares (including the indexes) and also the explain you have done?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the first select. You don't need to select any fields beyond `ipaddress`. You also don't need to order or group the result. If you want unique `ipaddress`es, just use `distinct`

```
select distinct ipaddress
from visit_count
where last_visit between '$firstDayOfMonth' and '$lastDayOfMonth' 
    and user_id = '$userId'
```

300 selects don't seem to be much, even with the second table having 50k rows. On my machine, even without indexes, it takes only a fraction of a second.

If you want to simplify it anyway, you can [`join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) the two tables with

```
select ipstart, ipend
from ipaddresses i
join visit_count v on inet_aton(v.ipaddress) between i.ipstart and i.ipend
where v.last_visit between '$firstDayOfMonth' and '$lastDayOfMonth'
    and v.userid = '$userId'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use better query like other suggested to you

2) Have you defined indexes for the field you need ?

3) Dont know if you use mysql or mysqli...anyway use fetch_assoc that is faster then fetch_array

with this 3 trick you should be ok